# Search a dataframe for values close to a list of numbers

Tags: r, search, dataframe

**NOTE: The 'dataframes' in this question are actually matrices. I have left the wording so that the answers still make sense, and because the solutions work on both dataframes and matrices**

I have a dataframe containing a list of masses and their corresponding intensities:

```
> df <- cbind(c(3.43534, 5.324, 9.322, 123.234), c(31, 4214, 112, 44))
> colnames(df) <- c("Mass", "I")
> df
          Mass    I
[1,]   3.43534   31
[2,]   5.32400 4214
[3,]   9.32200  112
[4,] 123.23400   44
```

I have another dataframe containing a list of masses and the name of the corresponding compound:

```
> compounds <- cbind(c(3.39, 102.93, 9.310, 144.00), c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
> colnames(compounds) <- c("Mass", "Compound")
> compounds
     Mass     Compound
[1,] "3.39"   "A"     
[2,] "102.93" "B"     
[3,] "9.31"   "C"     
[4,] "144"    "D"
```

I want to be able to identify the compounds in the first df. This would be fairly straightforward if the masses were exact. However, due to experimental error the masses in the first dataframe are not numerically identical to those in the 'compounds' dataframe.

How can I search the compounds dataframe to find all rows with a mass close to one in the first df? For example allowing a tolerance of 0.2, which would give me:

```
     Mass     Compound
[1,] "3.39"   "A"     
[2,] "9.31"   "C"
```

The real life data is thousands of rows, so unfortunately a loop would be too slow.

Comment: Those are matrices, not data frames.

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. I made this mistake because the full dataset I am using is a data.frame, though aichao's solution still works. Will change the wording now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
tol <- 0.2
compounds[which(do.call(pmin,as.data.frame(abs(outer(compounds$Mass, df$Mass, "-")))) < tol),]
##  Mass Compound
##1 3.39        A
##3 9.31        C
```

Notes:

1. Use `outer` with operator '-' to compute a difference matrix between each `compounds$Mass` and each `df$Mass`.
2. Take the `abs` of that to get a distance matrix.
3. Use `do.call(pmin,as.data.frame(...))` to compute the minimum distance for each row (i.e., each `compounds$Mass`)
4. Subset `compounds` using those rows for `which` the distance is less than your tolerance.

**Edited answer**

Actually, since we only want the `compounds` that are within `tol` of any row in `df`, we don't actually need to compute the minimum distance; therefore:

```
compounds[unique(which(abs(outer(compounds$Mass, df$Mass, "-")) < tol, arr.ind=TRUE)[,1]),]
##  Mass Compound
##1 3.39        A
##3 9.31        C
```

which will be a bit faster.

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Mass = c(3.43534, 5.324, 9.322, 123.234), I = c(31, 
4214, 112, 44)), .Names = c("Mass", "I"), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = "data.frame")
##       Mass    I
##1   3.43534   31
##2   5.32400 4214
##3   9.32200  112
##4 123.23400   44

compounds <- structure(list(Mass = c(3.39, 102.93, 9.31), Compound = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Mass", "Compound"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
##    Mass Compound
##1   3.39        A
##2 102.93        B
##3   9.31        C
##4 144.00        D
```

Comment: Very interesting solution, although it still does a loop due to `do.call.`

Comment: Thank you both! Just testing out each solution to see which works faster on the full-size dataset.

Comment: @Gopala: actually, I don't think so because the `do.call` is there to call `pmin`, which is parallel min over a list (i.e., the columns of the distance matrix). This is why we convert using `as.data.frame` which gives a list of columns.

Comment: It has to, on a row-by-row basis, but that is not the same as an n-squared loop. So, I do agree it is more optimized.

Comment: @DGreenwood: you may want to checkout my edited answer, which should be a bit quicker still.

Comment: Thanks @aichao. Just tested both on my big dataset and your second solution took a third of the time.

Comment: @DGreenwood: yes, the second solution does not compute the minimum distance; it just looks for `compounds` whose distances are below the tolerance to any row in `df`; hence it is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution I can come up with as to how to join the two data sets and then filter based on desired condition:

```
df <- data.frame(Mass = c(3.43534, 5.324, 9.322, 123.234),
                 I = c(31, 4214, 112, 44))
compounds <- data.frame(Mass = c(3.39, 102.93, 9.310, 144.00),
                        Compound = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <- expand.grid(df$Mass, 1:nrow(compounds))
df <- cbind(Var1 = df$Var1, compounds[df$Var2, ])
unique(df[(df$Mass > df$Var1 - 0.2 & df$Mass < df$Var1 + 0.2),
           c('Mass', 'Compound')])
```

Comment: Be cautious on this one as it might use up too much memory depending on data size.

Comment: Error: object 'x' not found

Comment: Sorry about that. I changed the name from x to df but did not fix it fully. Now, edited.